# NHibernate 5 EntityMode is not a member of ISessionImplementor

Tags: nhibernate

I'm upgrading from NHibernate 4 to 5 and I cannot compile my code because of the following error: "EntityMode is not a member of ISessionImplementor"

My code was copied from here: https://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/finding-dirty-properties-in-nhibernate.html

Any idea, what happened with EntityMode in ISessionImplementor?

Comment: Just remove that argument. `Object [] currentState = persister.GetPropertyValues(entity);`

Answer (score 1):

While upgrading to NHibernate 5 I came accross the same issue. It seems that [this change](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/commit/13081b244fbfb97b2c8690fb03585d29f9c72182#diff-fcb0f2b4d825975be4e65de95ea6cfb0) removed the `EntityMode` argument from `GetPropertyValues`, so yes, the argument version is removed in NHibernate 5. The release notes have the change listed under removed features: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.6/releasenotes.txt#L654.

From what I can `ISessionImplementor.EntityMode` anyways only returned `EntityMode.Poco` and `GetPropertyValues` only checked if the passed `EntityMode` is `EntityMode.Poco`. So it seems save to just remove that argument, no other change needed replacing it. Given that @hazzik was the author of said change give that advice more credibility too.